# how to show that $A_{k-1} \subset 3A_{k} $ where $ A_k $ are iterations of the Cantor set ???

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

For example

$A_1 = [0,1/3] \cup [2/3 , 1] $

$A_2 = [0, 1/9] \cup[2/9 ,1/3] \cup [2/3 ,7/9] \cup [ 8/9 ,1]$

Note that

$3 (A_2) = A_1 \cup D $   , for some set $D$

In the general case, I want to show that

$A_{k-1} \subset  3A_{k} $

I know that by multiplying(for 3) the primitives $ 2^{k -1} $ ranges of $ A_k $ I will be able to generate the $ A_{k-1} $ but I do not know how to demonstrate this.

How can I do it?

Comment: What definition of $A_k$ are you starting from? It's hard to answer your question without knowing that.

Comment: The definition of the Cantor set
  pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

Answer (score 1):

Using [the definition that you linked in your comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set), and changing from $C_n$ notation to your $A_k$ notation, one obtains
$$\frac{A_{k-1}}{3} \cup \left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{A_{k-1}}{3}  \right) = A_k
$$
Multiplying both sides by $3$ one gets
$$A_{k-1} \cup (2 + A_{k-1}) = 3A_k
$$
and therefore 
$$A_{k-1} \subset 3 A_k
$$
To be more specific, using that $A_{k-1} \subset [0,1]$ and that $A_k \subset [0,1]$, and that $2+A_{k-1} \subset [2,3]$, it follows from this that $A_{k-1} = 3 A_k \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: It's because I actually wanted to show this result by using the Cantor set construction in the traditional way, dividing the interval into 3 parts and excluding the middle part, but if I could show that using this formula over $ C_n $ is the same thing of starting in 3 and excluding the middle, would also serve.